# How to rollback previous changes in ef codefirst model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on asp.net mvc with EF codefirst. I am trying to update the list of records at once. like,

```
foreach(var pat in listpats)
{
context.Entry<Patient>(pat).state=EntityState.Modified;
context.savechanges();
}
```

and its working fine for me. Now suppose if listpats contains 10 items, if i got exception at 7th item while i am updating. it will save first 6 items. but i want to save all records at once if no error occurred while updating. if any error occurred mean while i should rollback all the previous changes. so how could i achieve this using EF code first model. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke SaveChanges() outside foreach:

```
foreach(var pat in listpats)
{
    context.Entry<Patient>(pat).state=EntityState.Modified;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

This way if an exception occurs everything will be rolled back

Answer (score 0):

If you've modified the entities in some other code then their state will be modified (within the same context) without you having to explicitly change it with a foreach loop and context.Entry(pat).state=EntityState.Modified.

So taking a step back, after you've modified all your patients entities a single call to context.SaveChanges() will automagically rollback on error.

Soooo to summarise, change all the patients entities and afterwards call context.SaveChanges() which will make EF propogate all the entities that have a modified state (the state change happens when you modify the entity) to the DB, context.SaveChanges() will handle simple cases like this with regards to rollback.

P.S. Your question is making me wonder if you've changed the patients in a different context and that's why your manually changing the current context' state.